# Top Admin Bar Never Shows Up

Tags: admin-bar, site-url

So I recently moved a site to a new domain and updated the URL to reflect the changes in the database as well as in the wordpress backend. wp_head and wp_footer are placed respectively in header.php and footer.php, however the top admin bar has never shown up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Get into your WordPress dashboard, from **Users » Your Profile**, and **check** the *"Show Toolbar when viewing site"*.

[image: Show admin bar from user profile]